# How can I load changes of .el file at startup in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have installed Emacs under Windows 7 and want to use it in my everyday work. Unfortunately Emacs world and other text editors world are completely different and I am getting stuck on every third sequence of keys pressed on keyboard - it's doing something that I don't expect it would do.

I want to make a panic command - when I press ESC ESC ESC it stops doing everything, quitting from minibuffer, stops entering command, unhighlight regexps, etc. It already does what I want, except it killing buffers, the layout of my workspace. So I modified `keyboard-escape-quit` function in simple.el file (found it by C-h k ESC ESC ESC)

```
(defun keyboard-escape-quit ()
  "Exit the current \"mode\" (in a generalized sense of the word).
   This command can exit an interactive command such as `query-replace',
   can clear out a prefix argument or a region,
   can get out of the minibuffer or other recursive edit,
   cancel the use of the current buffer (for special-purpose buffers),
   or go back to just one window (by deleting all but the selected window)."
  (interactive)
  ; Stop highlighting regexp
  (unhighlight-regexp)
  (cond ((eq last-command 'mode-exited) nil)
    ((region-active-p)
     (deactivate-mark))
    ((> (minibuffer-depth) 0)
     (abort-recursive-edit))
     (current-prefix-arg
     nil)
    ((> (recursion-depth) 0)
     (exit-recursive-edit))
     (buffer-quit-function
     (funcall buffer-quit-function))
   ;((not (one-window-p t))
   ; (delete-other-windows))
    ((string-match "^ \\*" (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
     (bury-buffer))))
```

I have byte-compiled and loaded this file and it works ok. But I can't figure out why it is not loading at startup.

Comment: i'm newb, but can you just put this code in your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`, and thus overwrite previous definition? (Windows, it may be `c:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\_emacs`.) I try not to rely on editing source files, as then you'll have to worry about it possibly at some point. (Reinstall, troubleshooting, checking out bleeding edge when interacting with support.)

Comment: So as I understand now all user customizations are done through the init.el at .emacs.d directory. And the safe way to do them is to add new functions, bind new keys to them or rebind existing ones.

Comment: @user2244092 I think that you should at least skim through the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html).  It thoroughly explains all concepts of Emacs, including [Customization](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customization.html#Customization) and the [Init File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify some special built-in libraries, including `simple.el`.  Emacs never actually loads these special libraries from their source or byte code files.  Their byte code is directly included in the Emacs executable at build time, by a process called “dumping”.  Emacs loads these libraries from its own binary.

Generally, should **not** modify any built-in libraries anyway.  Your risk breakage, and your customizations are lost when you update Emacs.

Instead, do what you are supposed to do: Add custom functions to your `init.el`.

Hence, instead of modifying the built-in `keyboard-escape-quit`, create your own function, e.g. `my-emergency-quit`, in your `init.el`, and bind it to a global key, e.g. `C-c q`, with

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c q") #'my-emergency-quit)
```

Some final words of advice:  I do not think that such a panic command does any good.  The first rule of Emacs is: Don't panic.  If you are stuck, don't try to quit and kill everything.  Rather, try to find out why you are stuck, and how to get “un-stuck” by normal means.  You'll learn Emacs better this way, imho.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for advice, maybe you are right.